# Access parent methods from component template in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this code:

```
     new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            'app-component': AppComponent
        },
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
        },
        methods: {
            doSomething: function(){
                console.log('arrived!')
            }
        }
    })
```

How can I call "doSomething" method from AppComponent html template? like this:

```
<app-component>  
    <a href="#" v-on:click="doSomething()">text</a>
</app-component>
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: scope.doSomething is not a function

Comment: try `v-on:click="doSomething"`

Comment: @maioman I got this: [Vue warn]: v-on:click="doSomething" expects a function value, got undefined (found in component: <app-component>)

Answer (score 12):

try `v-on:click="$parent.doSomething()"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, based on [this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/vuejs-acces-parent-methods).

```
this.$parent.$options.methods.someParentMethod(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $dispatch from the child to trigger an event. Example:

```
// App component
<app-component>  
    <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="$dispatch('do-something')">text</a>
</app-component>


// Parent
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'app-component': AppComponent
    },
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    },
    events: {
        'do-something': function(){
            console.log('arrived!')
        }
    }
});
```

For more info on parent-child communication, check the documentation:
http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Is there any solution without events? like prototyping Vue instance or etc.

Comment: @saeedhbi I was trying to achieve something similar to you, i.e. put all the shared/common methods in a base component and then extend the base component to create new components which require the shared/common methods. Using mixins or custom plugin seems to be a more elegant solution. I am currently using the mixin approach, wherein I have all the shared methods in a mixin and whenever any component requires those shared methods, I use the mixin in that component. Mixins in Vue are just like `trait in php`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Off cause, mixins is the answer! Thank you!

Comment: in Vue 2.x, it is replaced by `$emit`, for details, please refer to [Vue's migration note](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Wiljan response, I extend all components with new Vue instance that has methods and data. Now I access to methods and etc.

Comment: Can you expand on that? I'm not sure, but it sounds like something one should definitely not do...

Comment: @LinusBorg I don't want to share methods with props or events and these methods and data are global like user or company and must be shared all over application even components. And I don't want use them with $parent or $dispatch or etc. On each component I use "extends" property to get it and use on this. Now I access to method name into component template. I know components are isole and it is better to be isolate, But I think this does not defeats anything.